# React router v5 with history - no content shown on routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm banging my head for what I'm missing here. My routing worked fine as long as I used `BrowserRouter`:

`import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'`

But now I want to navigate programmatically outside my components (in a saga) and for that I switched to `Router` with `history`

```js
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
const history = createBrowserHistory()
export default history

// index.js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './app/history'

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Component />
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
```

And now when I hit refresh I see the content of the route, but if I try to navigate with either history or by clicking a `Link`, no route is getting rendered, just the url changes.

What am I missing?

I also tried `import { Router } from 'react-router'` and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820799/react-and-antd-router-doesnt-re-render-components/64822114?noredirect=1#comment114608967_64822114) will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like many people have been discussing about this issue which is using the `history` latest version `>=5` causing this issue.

It seems to be working normally with `4.x` version such as `4.10.1` so you might need to downgrade `history` version to make it work for now.

```js
{
  "history": "4.10.1",
}
```

Here are the open issues:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/803
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/805

I'm guessing there are people working on the fix. Let's see then we would update again.

Comment: I'm having a demo which is using the v4 working normally which using both `<Link />` and history api here https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dhawan-27f6d?file=/src/App.js. Can you check and compare things? It won't work as expected in case of switching to use v5

Comment: Thank you for that, I also got another project in which everything is working. And I didn't find anything in the comparison. That's why I opened this bounty. As far as I can tell we don't have any differences

Comment: No, your demo would be what I would upload as a demo. what I'm looking for are things I might be missing in my own code.

Comment: that's very odd, I haven't made a single change and it's working now ... might be that the react router has downgraded it's history dep to version 4? I don't have history explicitly as a dep. anyway, thanks for your input!