# React and antd: Router doesn't re-render components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

I have a simple web page with login and search pages. I also have a navbar at the top to allow for switching between the two. The basic `App.js` looks as follows:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <CustomLayout>
                <Switch>
                    <BaseRouter/>
                </Switch>
            </CustomLayout>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Now, the `BaseRouter` and `CustomLayout` are just

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path={"/list"} component={ItemsList}/>
        <Route path={"/login"} component={LoginForm}/>
    </div>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

and

```
const CustomLayout = ({children}) => {
    return(
        <>
        <Navbar/>
        {children}
        </>
    );
}

export default CustomLayout;
```

Now, the navbar looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import {Menu} from 'antd';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

 const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Menu mode="horizontal" theme={"dark"}>
                <Menu.Item key="list">
                    <Link to={"/list"}>List</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key={"login"}>
                    <Link to={"/login"}>Sign in</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar
```

Let's keep components simple:

```
const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            login
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login

const List = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            list
        </div>
    );
}

export default List
```

Now the problem is that when I click on links in the navbar, React doesn't re-render components even though the route changes. I've seen hundreds of answers on SO but I still can't figure it out.
**NOTE**
It is important for me to avoid refreshing or reloading the page.
**EDIT**
Strangely enough, when I change `Router` to `BrowserRotuer` it works fine, but I can't use my own history then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` package.

- `App.js`:- use `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <CustomLayout>
        <Switch>
          <BaseRouter/>
        </Switch>
      </CustomLayout>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

- `BaseRouter.js`:- import `Route` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const BaseRouter = () => (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/list" component={ItemsList}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
  </div>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

- `Navbar.js`:-

```
import React from "react";
import {Menu} from 'antd';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu mode="horizontal" theme={"dark"}>
        <Menu.Item key={"list"}>
          <Link to="/list">List</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key={"login"}>
          <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar
```

then if you want to use `history`:-

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const testFunctionComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  
  const handleClick = (urlPath) => {
    // you can do
    history.push(urlPath) // to go anywhere 
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('/anypath')}>Click Me!<button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: To whomever that reads this: this is the easiest way to go. I also found that if you use `BrowserRouter` you can call `props.history.push()` in whichever component you like.

Comment: Yes. That's true for all components being the children under the `BrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `BaseRouter` from this :

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path={"/list"} component={ItemsList}/>
        <Route path={"/login"} component={LoginForm}/>
    </div>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

To this :

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/list" component={ItemsList}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
    </div>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot have the div inside the switch. You're not exposing the Route components to your switch statement.

Therefore, your url changes because your Navbar makes it change but your switch doesn't know what to do.

Try changing your base router to this:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <CustomLayout>

                    <BaseRouter/>

            </CustomLayout>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/list"} component={ItemsList}/>
        <Route path={"/login"} component={LoginForm}/>
    </Switch>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

`Router` is low-level and expects you to manage things. `BrowserRouter` already syncs with HTML5 history. If you want `Router`, I think you have to manage the syncing yourself (e.g. `<Link onClick={() => history.push(href)}>)` or listen to history for change detection. See [Detect Route Change with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router)

Comment: Does this explain why I was getting a warning  : `You cannot change the history of Router`

Comment: This is true, but there are much easier ways to go, e.g. `useLocation` hook